# Install PHP on RedHat

Tags: linux, php, redhat

I just ran `yum install php` in the command prompt. Everything went fine ('complete!') as per the dialogue.  I then uploaded a file that does not use short tags and is named with the proper extension (i.e., the name is test.php).

```
<?php print "hello world"; ?>
```

When I navigate my browser to test.php it just prints each of the characters shown above; i.e., PHP is not interpreting it.

What might be the problem? Also, if there is a configuration file that needs to be updated, please tell me what directory path I am likely to find that file.

**Edit:**
Apache2 & Red Hat Enterprise 5.5

Comment: Saying that you run `"Redhat"` is worthless. What version? Perhaps you should read [ask] and then re-write your question.

Comment: Yes, I am new to setting up servers. I acknowledeged, I should have put the edditions in. I tried to give a detailed description from the perspective of a newb dealing with a command line. I thought this was a place for learning (at any level). Why the '-1'?

Comment: The -1 wasn't from me, but I'd guess that it's from the complete lack of detail.

Comment: I reread the rules, I don't know what else I am missing.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on [meta]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
yum install mod_php
```

This will load the php module for Apache.

Comment: This will install the php module for Apache, but you should still check your config files and make sure it will be loaded.

Comment: The conf file should automatically be placed in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory

Comment: This installs php-5.4.16 on RHEL 7, it doesn't install PHP7.

Answer (score 1):

Check apache (I presume you are running apache) is actually loading the php module, and has the correct handlers setup for .php files.

Sounds like a web server issue rather than a php issue.

Comment: Yes. I am running Apache2.